# Efecto fade in con timer en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

he implementado una función que cambia la propiedad background de una cabecera cada cierto tiempo, estoy intentado que la transición sea suave, mediante alguna función de jquery tipo fade in, pero no doy con la tecla ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Mi código JS es el siguiente:

```js
            var body = $('.main-header .container');
    var backgrounds = [
      'url(http://imagen1.jpeg)', 
      'url(http://imagen2.jpg)'];
    var current = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        body.css(
            'background',
        backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);

        setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
    }
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
    body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qué tal? Al estar usando setTimeout() le obliga a crear un fadeIn y un fadeOut. Lo que faltaría sería agregarlos. Usé colores para el ejemplo, pero igual aplica en imágenes.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
      Cambios de colores con efecto
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
  var body = $(".container");
    var backgrounds = ["red", "blue","yellow"];
    var current = 0;
    
     function nextBackground(){
      body.fadeOut(3000,function(){
        body.css(
          "background",backgrounds[(current = ++current % backgrounds.length)]
        );
        body.fadeIn(3000,function(){
          setTimeout(nextBackground, 3000);
        });
      });
    }
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 3000);
    
    body.css("background", backgrounds[0]);
```

Si desea modificar aun mejor los efectos:[https://www.anerbarrena.com/jquery-fadein-y-fadeout-3114/#:~:text=Sintaxis%20de%20jQuery%20fadeIn(),extra%C3%ADda%20de%20su%20web%20oficial.&text=Vemos%20que%20la%20funci%C3%B3n%20tiene,elemento%20con%20el%20queremos%20interactuar](https://www.anerbarrena.com/jquery-fadein-y-fadeout-3114/#:%7E:text=Sintaxis%20de%20jQuery%20fadeIn(),extra%C3%ADda%20de%20su%20web%20oficial.&text=Vemos%20que%20la%20funci%C3%B3n%20tiene,elemento%20con%20el%20queremos%20interactuar)

Espero ser de ayuda, saludos!